# How do I enable IFormFeature in ASP.Net / Kestrel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I want to process multi-part file uploads, so in my handler I get the `IFormFeature` like this:

```ml
var formFeature = ctx.Features.Get<IFormFeature>()
```

However, it is always `null`.

My request looks like this:

```sh
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F records=@big-file.csv localhost:8080/form
```

**What do I need to do to enable `IFormFeature` in ASP.Net / Kestrel?**

Comment: A search of the aspnet.core github for `IFormFeature` comes up with 11 hits (mostly tests). There are only two places that *set* the feature [ex](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Http/Http/src/RequestFormReaderExtensions.cs#L46) they both require the request to have a form content type. Just to validate that your header is being recognized, can you check the value of `ctx.Request.HasFormContentType`?

Comment: From the `curl` command, I set the content type to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, I can see that. I'm asking if you've verified that aspnet has properly detected it as such

Comment: I added a quick print `HasFormContentType? true` yes it does

Comment: I don't have an answer for you. I was suggesting that's a place start. It should be set automatically for you, there's nothing you need to add that I'm aware of to enable any of this. I'd ask on their github or gitter if you don't get an answer

Comment: Context may be necessary as well. From where are you trying to access? Controller, Middleware, something else?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem and solved it by accident. Excuse my fsharp.

*Get*ting:

```
let formContentType = ctx.Request.HasFormContentType
```

results in *formFeature*:

```
let formFeature = ctx.Features.Get<IFormFeature>()
```

no longer being null.

Commenting out `let formContentType = ctx.Request.HasFormContentType` results in *formFeature* being null again.

So it appears as though getter on that property is triggering something to resolve which otherwise does not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the IFormFeature directly, call HttpRequest.ReadFormAsync() to parse the incoming form.
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.readformasync
IFormFeature is just for caching the results, that's why it doesn't exist until any of the form APIs are called (not just HasFormContentType).